# What data size (kB) will JavaScript object take up within an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

Given a JavaScript object:

```
var data = {
  foo: 'bar',
  answer: 42,
  bestXmlParser: 'regex'
  ...
}
```

How can I determine what size this would take up in an HTTP request?

This would be using plain ASCII characters only.

Eventually, the object will be converted to XML (SOAP object via `node-soap`) and transferred as whatever encoding SOAP protocol uses (I assume character, but not sure).

I know there is overhead and this will not exactly equal the size of the HTTP request I end up making, especially after converted to XML

However the rough size I determine from the object itself will help me throttle my request size and avoid generating `HTTP 413 Request Entity Too Large`

Comment: That depends on how you encode the object. An object is simply some area in memory. If you want to send the data via HTTP, you have to first converted to something that is transmittable via HTTP (probably character data).

Comment: The request will have overhead from headers etc as well

Comment: Thank you, I updated the Q with what I know about the encoding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Send the XHR request to your server and open the **Network** tab in Chrome Developer Tools.
2. Once opened, click on the link that represents the XHR request you just made.
3. Look for the **Content-Length** http header under Response or Request headers.

That number is the number of bytes of data in the body of the response or request.

**UPDATE:**

Also Blobs can tell you the bytes. Example:

```
var b = new Blob(['{"test":"one two three"}'], {type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});
b.size //=> 24
```

The data can be of different types (*String, ArrayBuffer, Blob*) and in any order. Example:

```
var b24 = new Blob(['{"test":"one two three"}'], {type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});
var b18 = new Blob(['Hello cruel world!'], {type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});

var blob = new Blob(['hello world', b24, b18]);
blob.size //=> 53, (24+18+11 = 53 bytes)
```

More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob

**UPDATE 2:**

In Node.js it looks like `Buffers` can be used to accomplish the same thing. More here: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_bytelength_string_encoding

Example:

```
> str = 'hello world'
> Buffer.byteLength(str, 'utf8') + ' bytes'
'11 bytes'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm more looking for a way to get this programmatically, within my app itself.

Comment: Using the example he provided you could do it fairly easily...  var b = new Blob([data], {type: "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"});  console.log(b.size);

Comment: Cool, thanks! Seems promising.  Is there an equivalent approach in Node.js?  I noticed `Blob` wasn't a global there.

Comment: Thanks it worked for my purpose, I'm not sure if this is the same data size in HTTP request though

Comment: I would think that bytes are bytes regardless of how they're used, unless there is some aggressive compression happening on the HTTP level... not sure about that. But even if that's the case, the bytes would appears as less and not more than the original. I think Node Buffers/Browser Blobs show you the original/raw bytes.